# merge columns, if values are not same take any non null value using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Input:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [['tom', 'Delhi', 'Jaipur'], ['nick', 'Delhi', 'Delhi'], ['juli', '', 'Noida'], ['rob', 'Gurugram', ''], ['dan', '', '']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'City1', 'City2']) 

   Name     City1   City2
0   tom     Delhi  Jaipur
1  nick     Delhi   Delhi
2  juli             Noida
3  rob   Gurugram        
4  dan
```

Expected Output: If values are same take any, if not the take any non-null if possible

```
   Name      City
0   tom     Delhi
1  nick     Delhi
2  juli     Noida
3  rob   Gurugram        
4  dan
```

I tried looking for merge column [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-two-text-columns-into-a-single-column-in-pandas/) , but it didn't help in my case.

Comment: empty values are misisng values? Like `data = [['tom', 'Delhi', 'Jaipur'],
        ['nick', 'Delhi', 'Delhi'], 
        ['juli', np.nan, 'Noida'], 
        ['rob', 'Gurugram', np.nan],
        ['dan', np.nan, np.nan]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'City1', 'City2'])` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use if empty values are empty strings use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract columns:

```
df['City'] = np.where(df['City1'].eq(''), df.pop('City2'), df.pop('City1'))
print (df)
   Name      City
0   tom     Delhi
1  nick     Delhi
2  juli     Noida
3   rob  Gurugram
4   dan
```

If empty values are `NaN`s use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
data = [['tom', 'Delhi', 'Jaipur'],
        ['nick', 'Delhi', 'Delhi'], 
        ['juli', np.nan, 'Noida'], 
        ['rob', 'Gurugram', np.nan],
        ['dan', np.nan, np.nan]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'City1', 'City2'])


df['City'] = df.pop('City1').fillna(df.pop('City2'))
print (df)
   Name      City
0   tom     Delhi
1  nick     Delhi
2  juli     Noida
3   rob  Gurugram
4   dan       NaN
```

If possible multiple columns `City` is possible replace empty string to missing values, back filling missing rows and select first column by position:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('Name')
         .replace('',np.nan)
         .bfill(axis=1)
         .iloc[:, 0]
         .reset_index(name='City'))
print (df1)
   Name      City
0   tom     Delhi
1  nick     Delhi
2  juli     Noida
3   rob  Gurugram
4   dan       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['City'] = df['City1'].replace('',df['City2'])
df.drop(['City1', 'City2'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df
   Name      City
0   tom     Delhi
1  nick     Delhi
2  juli     Noida
3   rob  Gurugram
4   dan
```